# Radio button inside select 2 options angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angularjs-select2

Is there a way to have a radio button attached to the options in the select in angularjs ?

This will be something like a radio button for each item in the dropdown list.

I used the ng-html-bind to add the radio button but that is not working out.

I am using the normal select and tried with deprecated ui-select2 .Nothing works but for the new angular-ui ,ui-select it works

Comment: Of course it's possible. How easy it is, is another question.

Comment: @dfsq do you have some examples if you have tried that before ? For some reasons I am not able to get it work :(

Comment: I never tried it before, but I know that you can format dropdown items with custom HTML. So I wouldn't expect it to be very difficult. But yes, post your code, and demo if you have anything.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ynvvx7zw/   I am using an available example as shown. When I tried to get a radio button instead of the unicode, it doesn;t work. But the requirement is that instead of those unicode symbols,radio buttons are required.